# What is the oldest precisely dated event?

Tags: ancient-history, date

I'm wondering what is the oldest date we can *precisely* place on ancient events. Ideally, I would like to know the oldest human event that we know (at least today) the exact day it happened (with respect to our own modern calendar).

My best guess would be something linked to a [solar eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mursili's_eclipse), though there tends to be uncertainty on which eclipse the event is associated with.

What is the oldest but precisely known event we know of, and how do we know its date?

Precision:

I want a human event that we can date as of today. An eclipse itself doesn't count, but any event that we know happened during the eclipse (or e.g. the next day) counts. The event does not need to be intentionally recorded, though my guess is it most probably was.

Comment: Do you want an event that was historically recorded, or an event we know must have happened (such as a solar eclipse itself) but have no specific records of aside from the necessary math?

Comment: @SPavel Edited. Hope this is clear enough.

Comment: May need to clarify "precisely" as well. Ancient records tended to use reginal dating (eg: 3rd year of the reign of King Suchandsuch), which in general cannot be unambiguously mapped to modern calendars. Even if there was an eclipse mentioned, those happen often enough that we might not know exactly which eclipse to map it to.

Comment: @T.E.D. Edited again. Hope this is understandable.

Comment: What is a "human event"? (you mention eclipses.)

Comment: I'm uncomfortable with closing a question for being a duplicate of **a closed question**. However, it may be legit to close it for the same reason the "duplicate" question was closed, if it has the same issue to the same or worse degree. And some argue that the fact that there's another question with answers is useful info to keep, even if both are closed.

Comment: @T.E.D. This indeed seems to be the same question. However, it seems to talk a lot about calendar nitpicking. Not sure if this one should be closed too. I have to admit that my definition of an event is a bit opinion-based though I don't think it is too much. Unless all ancient dates are subject to debate I don't think this should be seen as POB.

Comment: Though I'm not sure how I should edit to show the difference.

Comment: [October 22, 4004 BC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Ussher)! :D

Comment: What about events dated up to a year or several days?

Comment: @Anixx well, that's out of the scope of this question.

Comment: @PatJ What about events that definitely had human participants but left no mythology or written records, such as for instance a tree having traces from human interaction on its yearly cirles or a corpse found in volcanic ashes, when eruption's date is known?

Comment: @PatJ what about events like yearly celebrations, which are known to happen at certain date, but when the practice started is not exactly known?

Comment: @Anixx Both the tree and volcano work, though I'm pretty sure you can't age it precisely to the day. If you can be sure of when the regular celebration holds and show that it was in place, that may count.